# RabbitMq with rabbitmq-server command is not running

Tags: macos, rabbitmq, erlang, erl

I am trying to run Rabbitmq on my MAC CATALINA 10.15.5 and seeing this error everytime I run `rabbitmq-server` .

```
rabbitmq-server

Crash dump is being written to erl_crash.dump...done
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

the output of `rabbitmqctl status` is this:

```
{"init terminating in do_boot",{load_failed,[logger_filters,supervisor,error_logger,logger_backend,gen_event,erl_eval,file_server,logger_server,logger_simple_h,gen,file,lists,proc_lib,logger,file_io_server,kernel,filename,heart,error_handler,ets,application_master,code_server,code,application_controller,erl_parse,gen_server,logger_config,application,erl_lint]}}

Crash dump is being written to: erl_crash.dump...done
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

I tried uninstalling Erlang and Rabbitmq but still getting the same error.

what I am doing wrong here? I tried previous posts on this same topic but no help so far.

Comment: Did you ever have any success here? I'm seeing the same error seemingly out of the blue.

Comment: Its been a long time, but I think I didn't get the success initially, what I think was wrong that the default Erlang in my system was older and Rabbitmq will not work on that, so I deleted both Erlang, installed the new one and it was working.

Comment: As of today, attempting to start `rabbitmqctl` in a directory with Erlang 23 being the default fails with the above message. Making Erlang 24 the default starts it successfully. RabbitMQ version is 3.9.9 and I am on a Mac as well.